# using invoke inside a new thread in forms

Tags: c#, multithreading, invoke

While working on a C# forms program I have faced very annoying problem as following:
Suppose I have a `DataGridView` linked with database and of course I have to do some operations such insertion, modification, or even deletion.
If these operations done in the main `thread` then the form will hang on for a few seconds as operations require therefore I wrote each of these operations inside separated threads and that works well for now.However, if inside the thread I want to do some necessary code such DataGridView row selection it will pop-up a `cross-thread exception` and I did a little trick to do so using `this.invoke()` such here:

```
new thread( () => {
     // some operation code here such insert query, then...
     //search in DataGridView and highlight the result
     this.Invoke(new MethodInvoker(delegate
     {
     var i = 0; 
     foreach (DataGridViewRow r in dataGridView1.Rows)
     {
           if (r.Cells[1].Value.ToString().Equals(FirstName) && r.Cells[2].Value.ToString().Equals(LastName))
           {
                 r.Selected = true;
                 dataGridView1.CurrentCell = dataGridView1.Rows[i].Cells[1];
           }
      i++;
      }
      }));
}).start();
```

Then I ask if this doing of `invoke` usage will harm my code and may cause unpredicted sequences or it is totally safe ? what would be the other solution ?

Comment: There really isn't another solution. You have to be on the UI thread in order to access the grid (or any other UI object), and the way to do that is through `Invoke`.

Comment: then no worry about any unpredicted exception in the future ?

Comment: @JimMischel - "isn't another solution" is probably a bit too strong. One can dump updates to queue to be picked up by UI thread instead of direct `Invoke` for example.

Comment: Protip. Don't ever use the `Thread` class, use `ThreadPool` instead.

Comment: @Aron: See "When Not to Use Thread Pool Threads" at http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/0ka9477y(v=vs.110).aspx. The third and fourth items are pretty common scenarios.

Comment: "no worry about any unpredicted exception?" I don't know about that. `Invoke` just lets you avoid cross-thread exceptions due to accessing UI objects from non-UI threads. There's no telling what other exceptions might crop up in your code.

Comment: @JimMischel I agree that there are cases for true threads. But feel the OP isn't able to distinguish between them yet. Hence a simple hard rule seemed appropriate.

Comment: @JimMischel, hmm...what I meant by 'unpredicted exception' that I heard that using `invoke` in such scenario may complicates the issue more and more, is it right ?

Comment: @AlexeiLevenkov: Fair enough.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Then I ask if this doing of invoke usage will harm my code and may cause unpredicted sequences or it is totally safe ? what would be the other solution ?

This is the most common means of handling this.  That being said, if the `Thread` you create does nothing except `Invoke` back to the UI thread (ie: all of your work is inside of an `Invoke`), it will still block the UI, and provide no benefits at all.

If, however, you're doing your database insertions/deletions/etc on the thread, and only calling `Invoke` in small sections, this will provide a safe way to handle that.

Comment: so always recommended to use `invoke` in such context for a small piece of code and no future exception to worry about

Comment: @wisdom If I understand what you're saying, yes.  Try to keep the amount of code within each `Invoke` call (or `BeginInvoke` call) to a minimum.  The shorter that is, the less you'll potentially block.